# What's wrong with how I'm using akka unbecome

Tags: scala, akka

There is a scala class (from coursera reactive course)

```
class Counter extends Actor {
   def counter(n: Int): Receive = {
    case "inc" => context.become(counter(n + 1))        
    case "get" => sender ! n
  }

  def receive = counter(0)
}
```

All this actor does is increments counter by inc request and return current counter value via get request.
I thought that context.become adds new behaviour to the behaviour stack. So  if I add line

```
    case "dec" => context.unbecome()
```

it will restore previous behaviour from the stack and further get request will return previous value. But if i run

```
counter ! "inc"
counter ! "inc"
counter ! "inc"
counter ! "inc"

counter ! "dec"
counter ! "get"
```

Returned result is 0 but not 3 as I expected. Could anyone describe why?

Comment: Which call is returning 0? to get a response from `get`, you should call `counter ? "get"`

Comment: Note that `unbecome` here is useless. You should either call `become` with second argument `discardOld = false` or use `becomeStacked`.

Comment: Yes, case "inc" => context.become(counter(n + 1), false) does the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your call to `become` discards the previous behavior since the default value for the second argument, discardOld, is true. This default behavior is meant to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Calling unbecome when there is no state stack re-installs the original receive behavior.